# How should I create a Hex Keyboard?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm writing a Windows Phone 8 app using XAML.  I need to allow the user to input data as Binary, Hex, Octal, Decimal and ASCII.  I want to present the user a keyboard that matches their input choice.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6leFM.jpg) is a screenshot of the Windows Phone Calculator showing similar input choices as well as a mockup of what I would like to present to the user in HEX mode.

Is there a way I can create a custom keyboard layout?

Should I build the ui myself as buttons and hook the buttons up to key pressed commands?

Thanks for any advice.

[IntStarFoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2892400/intstarfoo)

Comment: I have had this on the back burner for a while now.  The whole custom keyboard thing works great unless you want to interact with the textbox.  I guess it won't be so hard to extend it... http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/PhoneTextBox/PhoneTextBox.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a custom keyboard layout using WP8. While you can control the specific keyboard that is selected through an `InputScope` with a `TextBox`, that's as much control as is offered.

As you need a completely custom UI, you'll need to lay the buttons out yourself. By creating a custom control template for the buttons, you'll be able to make them look as similar to the calculator buttons as you'd want.

Making the buttons look similar is reasonably simple with a new template and some styles.

[image: Example buttons]

```
<Style x:Key="CalculatorStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="#FF333333">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="NumberStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CalculatorStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF232323"/>
</Style>
```

In the template above, I tweaked some of the borders, colors, and margins to be similar to the example buttons.

Then putting them to use -- you could put them in a `Grid` for example.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CalculatorStyle}" Content="Mod" 
       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource NumberStyle}" Content="7" 
       Grid.Column="3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Available keyboard scopes you can find [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) - you can't change them.

So in your case you will have to build your own control imitating keyboard, you can read [the article on this blog](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx) about creating own keyboard. Maybe it will help.